# switching the a weapon

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

i made a character that has 5 frames:
1st nothing
2nd axe
3rd spear
4th sword
5th bow

i am trying to make it so the weapons will switch when i press the a,b,c,d,e button on the keyboard( i will figure out the actual button l8r) i have made a mc clip button to make it switch which works but i cant figure out how to do it from the key board

this is my code:

```
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
import flash.events.Event;

var abutton:Boolean;
var bbutton:Boolean;

stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, astage_onKeyDown);
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, astage_onEnterFrame);

function astage_onKeyDown(event:KeyboardEvent):void {
    if(event.keyCode == 65) {
        abutton = true;
    }
}

function astage_onEnterFrame(event:Event):void {
    if(abutton = true) {
        dude.gotoAndStop("bow");
    }
}

stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, bstage_onKeyDown);
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, bstage_onEnterFrame);

function bstage_onKeyDown(event:KeyboardEvent):void {
    if(event.keyCode == 66) {
        abutton = true;
    }
}

function bstage_onEnterFrame(event:Event):void {
    if(abutton = true) {
        dude.gotoAndStop("nothing");
    }
}
```

i have only tried it for the bow and nothing frame

Comment: and if anyone is willing to point me towards a better way to do this i'm open for options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like the following where 'a', 'b' & 'c' are your frame labels in 'character'.

FYI, in your code you have if(abutton = true); should be if(abutton == true) [equality NOT assignment].

```
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;

stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, onStageKeyDown);

function onStageKeyDown(event:KeyboardEvent):void {

    switch (event.keyCode) {

        case 65 :
            character.gotoAndStop('a');
            break;

        case 66 :   
            character.gotoAndStop('b');
            break;

        case 67 :
            character.gotoAndStop('c');
            break;

    }

}
```